# SQL Query to list all Table fields and Keys (Foreign & Primary)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-schema, database-administration

o/ Hello All,

I am trying to create a schema for an ERP that, laughable, doesn't have one for the 62 tables in its database. We, who I work for, don't have a DBA and thus am trying to sort through this on my own. In addition, I do not have DB owner rules and believe this limits what I can view; however, I have confirmed that is no standard schema/diagram

I searched and tried about a dozen queries I found on here but wasn't getting the information I am looking for.

Is there a sysobjects query that I can use to list all of the table's fields and appropriate keys? Aaaaaaaand, I'm new to SQL.  I can get around with queries, but on the administration side I have no clue. I am working on MS SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

Thanks good people.

[Partial view of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlqHH.png)

P.S. I understand this may appear as a duplicate, but I have been told time and time again by our IT department that the ERP's databases is a mess and was why they have been reluctant to auth me access. I think our ideas of standards may not be applicable with this particular database, hence the long post/descriptions.

Comment: I am sure you looked at the database diagrams tab?

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder Yes, I have. No joy.

Comment: @DipenShah No joy on both as both produced 0 results.

Comment: Can you actually confirm that any table has keys? I've worked in a few systems where they didn't.

Comment: On the diagrams, if the database is correctly setup, you should be able to autogenerate them to get an ERD. Goes without saying, to back up before trying stuff. See this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/

Comment: @SQLChao Certainly. There are, I am attempting to list them as we try and sort this out on the code side. 

http://prntscr.com/h2sud8

Comment: @DipenShah Got a partial on the former (http://prntscr.com/h2suzo) & to the latter, no results.

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder Unfortunately, I don't have those roles. http://prntscr.com/h2svxx

Comment: So the IT department wants you to build an ERD for the database which they state is a total mess. Then they say they can't give you access because it is a mess. And there is no DBA who could build this for you. Sounds to me like there is too many politics involved for you to be able to do your job. I would go back to the IT department and either tell them you need access or they just inherited a new project because they won't give you access.

Comment: @SeanLange Wow, your force is strong! You nailed it on the head.

Comment: If you don't have access to the information it is impossible to accomplish what you are trying to do. I would let the IT department deal with it if I were you. :)

Comment: i am one with the force and the force is with me

Answer (score 0):

I havn't worked with MS SQL for a long time, but i think you can use the following:

describe table_name 
OR
sp_columns table_name

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy as well. First one errored out, second produced no results.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will provide you with all the table names, column names, the data types for each column, width of the columns, whether a key is Primary or Secondary, and the referenced table and column for Foreign Keys.

```
SELECT SA.TABLE_NAME,
       SA.COLUMN_NAME, 
       SA.DATA_TYPE, 
       SA.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS Column_Width,
       PK.type AS PRIMARY_KEY,
       FK.type AS Foriegn_KEY, 
       SAU.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       SO.[Name] + '_' + SAU.COLUMN_NAME Referenced_Table_Column
FROM Stack.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS SA
LEFT JOIN STACK.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS SAU
    ON SAU.COLUMN_NAME = SA.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS FK
    ON FK.[NAME] = SAU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints AS PK
    ON PK.[NAME] = SAU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS SO 
    ON SO.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id OR
       SO.object_id = PK.parent_object_id
```

Possible Limitations:

1. You may not have enough permissions to the database to be able to run this query as it use sys tables and the information_schema.

Work Arounds:

1. Have you IT admins run the query for you and export the data to CSV or Excel file.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried to run it I got " Invalid object name 'Stack.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'."

Is this a permissions error that IT should be able to perform?

Comment: No it is not. [Stack.] is the table name. You need to replace Stack with the new table name. Sorry about this oversight on my part. Stack is my personal Stack Overflow help database. Just replace Stack with your data base so it looks like "[YourDatabase].information_schema.columns"

Comment: Also this request wasn't laughable many ERP's have this issue. I have personally experienced it more times than I would like to admit with vendor software especially ERP systems.

Comment: Ah, stack. Is that the tech term in this forum to replace with x, y or z? Also, that worked! Got em all. Thank you much good sir. 

I'm shocked many ERP's don't have this-just seems practical to have when creating such an environment. Guess I presumed incorrectly. 

Thanks again!

Comment: No, it is not a stack formatting standard. I just have a DB on my personal SQL Server named stack for developing answers and testing queries. I just forget to remove the name.